# Image in Laravel 5.6 markdown mail not visible in Gmail

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

## The problem

I am trying to send a QR image through a markdown mail. This image is in a controller and then passed to the mail format. Then inside I try to display the image with:

```
<img src="{{ $qr_image }}" alt="QR" title="QR" style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="200" height="200" data-auto-embed="attachment"/>
```

I am using the `eduardokum/laravel-mail-auto-embed` package. Now comes the odd part. When sending a mail to an outlook test account, the QR image shows without any problem at all. However when sending to a gmail account I get the following:  [image]. I have tried data-auto-embed="base64" but that didn't solve the provlem.

Is maybe there a way to reference to `$qr_image` with a file path, since google doesn't like base64?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail blocking small embedded inline images in email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946783/gmail-blocking-small-embedded-inline-images-in-email-template)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.4 embed image in mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503168/laravel-5-4-embed-image-in-mail)

Comment: did you get the correct image link??

Comment: Those solutions don't work for me. And they use the file path while I use a variable, don't know if that makes a difference. And I guess it is the correct link since it does work in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that the image is within the public directory. This could be somewhere like `public/img/emails/image.jpg`.

You will now be able to use the [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) helper which creates an absolute link to the file within the public directory. So the following should work:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/emails/' . $qr_image }}" alt="QR" title="QR" style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="200" height="200" data-auto-embed="attachment"/>
```

Assuming the `$qr_image` is just the name and extension of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $message->embed($pathToImage); ?>" style="max-width: 80%;padding-top: 20px;">
```

and in your controller something like this

```
'pathToImage' => public_path()."/images/1stgroup.jpeg"
```

Comment: I remember that $message is not avaiable in markdown