# Displaying logo in Laravel email notifications

Tags: php, laravel

Basically I want to display a logo in email notifications, so I did the following

First, copied the components by running the following statement

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Then in the `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php` I modified this `header` slot like this

```
@slot('header')
    @component('mail::header', ['url' => 'website address'])
        <img src="{{asset('logo.png')}}" alt="{{config('app.name')}}">
    @endcomponent
@endslot
```

The `logo.png` file is just sitting inside the `public` folder but when an email is sent, the logo doesn't show. An empty box is displayed instead like this
[image]

What possibly could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Inspect your email, look at the source of the image. If I am not wrong, `asset` includes full path.

Comment: Checkout this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503168/laravel-5-4-embed-image-in-mail